# Doubly linked list with remove?

Tags: rust

Is there such data type in Rust?

Someone on irc told me to use dlist but it doesn't have remove method, because it's based on dequeue. Though the algorithm seems [trivial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list#Removing_a_node)

Answer (score 1):

Not in the standard library (yet), but here's an experimental doubly-linked list with remove: https://github.com/contain-rs/linked-list

DroidLogician aired it [in this reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/33g3ek/erase_an_element_in_linkedlist/cqknh99).

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you link to for removal requires access to the node itself to get its `prev` and `next` pointers. The `DList` API in Rust doesn't reveal these nodes, only the data stored in the node, so a public `remove` method like that wouldn't make much sense. The `remove` method could in theory accept a parameter of the same type as the `DList` is storing, but there is no guarantee of uniqueness and the implementation would have to be `O(n)` instead.

The `DList` collection isn't based on a dequeue, but it is one of the collections in Rust that implement dequeue. My guess is that this is what the data structure is meant for, and as such there are no methods that modify the middle of the list, only the two ends of it.

As far as I can tell, the only way you could do this is either through some 3rd party library (there aren't any that I know of), or implement it yourself.